# fancyBox gallery Like not posting on facebook

Tags: fancybox, facebook-like, image-gallery

I have a site with a fancyBox gallery. I have added the Facebook like button to the gallery so I have a like for each image in the gallery. Problem is, that when clicking like on one of them, it doens't poste to facebook. However, it saves who likes what, so when others open the same gallery they can see who has liked what, but it's not posted.

I need to have each liked image to be posted on facebook.

I have tried with jsfiddle, but no matter what I do I can't get it to work: http://jsfiddle.net/sZG4L/

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".fancybox-button").attr('rel', 'gallery').fancybox({
        beforeShow: function () {
            if (this.title) {
                // New line
                this.title += '';

                // Add FaceBook like button
                this.title += '<iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=' + this.href + '&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=450&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=90" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:450px; height:90px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe>';
            }
        },
    helpers     : {
        title   : { type : 'inside' },
        buttons : {}
    },
    afterLoad : function() {
                this.title = (this.index + 1) + ' / ' + this.group.length + '  ';
    }
});
});
```

I guess I need some sort of variable, so my "this.href" points to each image, also after it is closed, maybe some dynamically function. I have been searching for this, but not been able to find out.

I have also tried updating the facebook like to html5, but then I'm not able to get it visible.

Hope someone can help.